# MongoDB Active-Active Multiple Datacenters

Tags: replication, mongodb, disaster-recovery

I am looking for a method to configure MongoDB servers across 2 different datacenters where they remain in an active-active configuration. Site A is the normal Production environment that customers access and all writes are sent here, but all data writes are also replicated to site B, which is the backup. Furthermore, site B should also be able to accept any writes and replicate that to site A. In the DR situation, and site A is gone, site B would have the complete data set and be switched to instantly (DNS only most likely) and nothing would need to be changed via the application.

I've done quite a bit of searching and I have yet found a solution. The closest I've found is sharded cluster, but that would require setting up multiple shards and each with replica-set and criss-cross where each replica-set is located between site A and B. This would also mean that regular writes to a shard with the primary Mongo instance located in the other datacenter to be traversing networks and be considerably slower.

Comment: Assume you've read the MongoDB White paper? I haven't but it seems like a good start.  https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/mongodb-multi-data-center-deployments

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is "master-master replication"; MongoDB does not support this, it only supports primary-secondary replication:

> [Replication in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication-in-mongodb)
>
> A replica set is a group of mongod instances that maintain the same data set. A replica set contains several data bearing nodes and optionally one arbiter node. Of the data bearing nodes, **one and only one member is deemed the primary node**, while the other nodes are deemed secondary nodes.